# What's the byte array in my generated protocol buffer code for?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

When I run `protoc` with `--go_out=.` on a `.proto` file, the generated Go source contains a byte slice literal. For example:

```
var File_pm_proto protoreflect.FileDescriptor

var file_pm_proto_rawDesc = []byte{
    0x0a, 0x08, 0x70, 0x6d, 0x2e, 0x70, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x22, 0x35, 0x0a, 0x07, 0x53, 0x74,
    0x61, 0x72, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x12, 0x12, 0x0a, 0x04, 0x6e, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x18, 0x01, 0x20,
    0x01, 0x28, 0x09, 0x52, 0x04, 0x6e, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x12, 0x16, 0x0a, 0x06, 0x70, 0x65, 0x61,
    0x6b, 0x38, 0x35, 0x18, 0x02, 0x20, 0x01, 0x28, 0x02, 0x52, 0x06, 0x70, 0x65, 0x61, 0x6b, 0x38,
    0x35, 0x42, 0x08, 0x5a, 0x06, 0x2e, 0x3b, 0x6d, 0x61, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x62, 0x06, 0x70, 0x72, 0x6f,
    0x74, 0x6f, 0x33,
}
```

What is encoded in this byte slice, and how is it used? Does it relate to encoding or decoding the wire format?

Comment: Looks relevant: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#self-description

Comment: Also relevant: https://blog.golang.org/protobuf-apiv2 -- this isn't a proper answer but: (1) the byte slice has a serialized version of the protocol message; (2 and 3) it may or may not be used while encoding or decoding an actual wire-format message, but those wire-format messages have their own serialization protocol that is not the same.

Comment: The key to understanding this is that the wire-format message is self-describing for its *data content* but that does not tell you how to *assign the values into an object in any of the various languages supported* (C++, C#, Python, and Go at least, and probably more). To generate a wire format message from a Go value, or produce a Go value from a wire format message, you need more stuff. How much more stuff, in what format, varies per source language.

Comment: When I look at the generated Go code from my builds, I get `612 bytes of a gzipped FileDescriptorProto` rather than the `rawDesc` you get, so clearly some details vary by protoc version and/or build time options. The format of this serialized descriptor is not directly documented: it's for internal use, in the Go routines.

Comment: Makes code unreadable, un-auditable, and not open source. Looks like the main problem here is that encoding and decoding is done with this cryptic byte arrays instead of readable code.